# Why PrimeNG p-calendar doens't show the value of the date?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am finding the following problem using PrimeNG Calendar component.

Into the HTML view of my Angular component I have defined this PrimeNG component tag:

```
<p-calendar [disabled]="disabled"
            [(ngModel)]="orderDetail.dettaglio_ordine.data_inserimento"
            dateFormat="yyyy-mm-dd"></p-calendar>
```

This should view the date contained into a JSON object field identified by **orderDetail.dettaglio_ordine.data_inserimento**. This field contains the following value: **2020-08-08"**

Infact in my JSON I have:

```
"data_inserimento": "2020-08-08",
```

the problem is that doing in this way this date is not shown into the rendered form that is empty.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to change the value from string to date , `p-calendar` value must be date so after you get the value from the api try to change it to date.

```js
  data_inserimento = new Date("2020-08-08");
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-rtkuz4?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Ok...a doubt...can I create a new Date directly into the frontend view? I mean doing it inline avoiding doing it into the .ts backend class?

Comment: as far I know you can't 